# How to compile AS3 from TexMate using Flex SDK?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, sdk, textmate, compiler-construction

How to compile AS3 from TexMate using Flex SDK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Floorplanner blog article](http://techblog.floorplanner.com/2009/09/05/build-actionscript3-projects-with-textmate-in-5-easy-steps/) is a nice read on setting up.

Also you might find [ProjectSprouts](http://projectsprouts.org/screencasts.html) interesting.

Comment: I swear I tweeted about this before your answer! http://twitter.com/#!/samuelgilman

Comment: yeah, I didn't check SO until after I found sprouts and that blog post. All in all doesn't matter. thanks for the comment.